Deserialization of Json in POJO. Nested object structure
Please give me an idea of how to build the structure of Java objects for deserialization of this Json. I ask you not to offer generators from the Internet (they cannot generate correct objects due to the Json structure).
  "objects" : {
    "Incident::123456" : {
      "code" : 0,
      "message" : "",
      "class" : "Inc",
      "key" : "1036022",
      "fields" : {
        "id" : "1654321",
        "title" : "title"
      }
    },
    "Incident::1046077" : {
      "code" : 0,
      "message" : "",
      "class" : "Inc",
      "key" : "1046077",
      "fields" : {
        "id" : "1654322",
        "title" : "title"
      }
    }
  },
  "code" : 0,
  "message" : "Found: 2"
}


The objects that come (like ""Incident::") have different values, their number can be infinitely large.
For each POJO, the fields of interest are in "fields" : {}
At first glance, the problem seems trivial to me, but I have not yet been able to solve it.
Is there a sane solution for such a structure? Could it be the right decision to create custom functionality?
As a result, I need to get a list of objects like:
public class Test {
    private int id; \\ from "fields" : {"id" : "1654322"}
    private String title; \\ from "fields" : {"title" : "title"}
}

Thank you.

What exactly is the problem here? If that is a properly built and valid JSON representation, you should be able to decode it with common tools. Mapping it to "a list of objects" is something you should write some code for

For example, I face the following problem:
If we consider the parent class, which should contain a collection of objects, how to explain to Jackson that the field names {"incident::123"} are not constant.
public record Tikets(HashMap<String,TiketClass> tiekt, int code, String message) {}

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you also have any code, share that too

You can use map.
class ObjectsOuter {

   Map<String, Incident> objects;

}

